# How to get duplicate geo-targetted sub-directories indexed when Google is ignoring the canonicals?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, subdirectory, country-specific, google-selected-canonical

I have a main website `example.com` which is mainly used for targeting one country. We recently started creating sub-directories for targeting other countries i.e, `example.com/us/`, `example.com/ph/` etc., We have replicated the same `example.com` and created sub-directories i.e, content and design are same. I have put canonical URL for sub-directories as `example.com`, as that is the primary domain.

Now, after optimizing sub directory pages based on country wise, I have changed certain sub directories canonical URL as `example.com/us/` - My sub-directories are not getting crawled or indexed. In search console, it shows me the error - "Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical"
I have changed canonical URLs but its been a month, the pages are not still not shown in the search results. What should I do to get my pages crawled?

Comment: It sounds like Googlebot crawled the URLs to me.   If Google knows they are duplicate, then they have been crawled. Why do you say they haven't been crawled?

Answer (score 1):

By adding the canonical meta link to your alternate language pages you're telling crawlers to ignore those pages and favour the **canonical** page.

In this case you need to be using `href-lang` meta data to direct crawlers to the correct page for a given language:

```
<!-- US English Site -->
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/us/" hreflang="en-us" />
<!-- General Portuguese -->
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.exampl.com/pt/" hreflang="pt" />
```

And then on your country pages you'd have a similar one linking back to the root version with the appropriate geo language.

More information on supported values and usage can be found on [Google's developer pages](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions).

I assume that your content isn't identical on each version if you are providing regional/country specific information? If it truly is identical, then there's probably not much value in duplicating it out if the site is using a generic TLD rather than a country specific one.